# Postman does not return the result in ASP.NET Core when calling third party API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am new to ASP.NET Core. I want to use this API: https://api.xmltime.com/holidays?.

I tried to get result in Postman, but it stopped at

```
var response = await _client.SendAsync(request);
```

when I am debugging.

This is my controller

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Index([FromQuery] string country, [FromQuery] int year)
{
    List<Holiday> holidays = new List<Holiday>();
    holidays = await _holidayService.GetHolidays(country, year);

    return Ok(holidays);
}
```

My service file

```
public class HolidayService : IHolidayService
{
    private readonly HttpClient _client;

    public HolidayService(IHttpClientFactory clientFactory)
    {
        _client = clientFactory.CreateClient("PublicHolidaysApi");
    }

    public async Task<List<Holiday>> GetHolidays(string country, int year)
    {
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, $"/holidays?accesskey=assdthf&secretkey=dffrnp7fvfaYq0u&version=3&country={country}&year={year}&lang=en");

        var response = await _client.SendAsync(request);   // postman request stopped here .WHY?

        using var responseStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();  

        return await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<List<Holiday>>(responseStream);
    }
}
```

My model classes:

```
public class Holiday
{
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public string UrliId { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public Country Country { get; set; }
    public Name Name { get; set; }
    public OneLiner OneLiner { get; set; }
    public Date Date { get; set; }
    public List<string> Type { get; set; }
    public string UId { get; set; }
}

public class Country
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Name
{
    public string NameLanguage { get; set; }
    public string NameText { get; set; }
}

public class OneLiner
{
    public string Language { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

public class Date
{
    public string iso { get; set; }
    public DateTime? date { get; set; }
}
```

`startup.cs`:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers();
    services.AddSingleton<IHolidayService, HolidayService>();
    services.AddHttpClient("PublicHolidaysApi", c => c.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.xmltime.com"));
}
```

What is the issue in my code? Please anyone help me.

Comment: What do you mean by Postman stops there? Postman can execute a call to your endpoint, and everything after that (once your controller method gets called) is up to your code. If your code isn't getting past that line, then check for an exception being thrown.

Comment: Do you mean - for some reason - your debugger does not hit `return Ok(holidays)`? Or if you are getting blank in `holidays`?

Comment: @toyalorswiftfan post man does not hit ` var response = await _client.SendAsync(request);`  this line and can not go to next line

Comment: @taylorswiftfan yes, postman request hits `var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, $"/holidays?accesskey=assdthf&secretkey=dffrnp7fvfaYq0u&version=3&country={country}&year={year}&lang=en");` this line. when the request move to `var response = await _client.SendAsync(request);` this line request is stopped

Comment: I see. Is there anything useful being thrown in logging (e.g. View > Output in VS)?